# How to send a specific parameter for PDF generation using FPDF and Retrofit library and download it into Android

Tags: php, android, retrofit, retrofit2, fpdf

I want to send the variable parameter key from Android to FPDF variable in API Server which will generate a set of report based on date range, but the variable in FPDF API wasn't receiving the Android's variable sent.
How to do this? Which `Call<>` should I use?

I already tried to use `Call<ResponseBody>` in order to sent the parameter. I am also tried to test it if the connection to the targeted file is success below `onResponse` and it response true.
But, when the time come for downloading the file into the device I tried to target the download link straightly to the file path in the server.
But after opening the downloaded file what I get is a blank data table which explain that the variable in the FPDF didn't receive the Android variable sent.

Here are my **downloadPDF()** method, to send the parameter to FPDF API:

```
private void downloadPDF() {
        RestApi api = RetroFit.getInstanceRetrofit();
        Call<ResponseBody> printCall = api.getPrint(
                strDateFrom,
                strDateTo
        );
        printCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                downloadManager();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No data :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

**Interface** method:

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("somepath/get_print.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> getPrint(
            @Field("keyDateFrom") String from,
            @Field("keyDateTo") String to
    );
```

**downloadManager()** method:

```
private void downloadManager() {
        DownloadManager downloadService = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://someweb.com/somefolder/get_print.php");
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    }
```

And my **get_print.php** script:

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$keyDateFrom = $_POST["keyDateFrom"];

$keyDateTo = $_POST["keyDateTo"];

require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Image('logo_hsp_transparan.png',10,10,30,15);

$pdf->SetLeftMargin(20);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(190,7,'Daftar Peminjaman Kendaraan HSPnet',0,1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
$pdf->Cell(190,7,'Jl. Tanah Merdeka No.1, RT.10/RW.3, Rambutan, Ciracas, Kota Jakarta Timur',0,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(10,7,'',0,1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
$pdf->Cell(190,7, $keyDateFrom ,0,1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
$pdf->Cell(190,7,'to',0,1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
$pdf->Cell(190,7, $keyDateTo ,0,1,'C');

$pdf->SetLeftMargin(32);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
$pdf->Cell(10,7,'',0,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(6,6,'NO',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(35,6,'TUJUAN',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(23,6,'PEMINJAM',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(35,6,'KENDARAAN',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(28,6,'JAM BERANGKAT',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(28,6,'JAM PULANG',1,1,'C');

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);

$query = mysqli_query($link,
"SELECT some_column
FROM `SOME_TABLE`
WHERE (DATE(some_column) BETWEEN '$keyDateFrom' AND '$keyDateTo')");

$i = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $pdf->Cell(6,6,$i++,1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(35,6,$row['some_column'],1,0);
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I mean, how to make the variable in FPDF API receiving the value from Android, so Android can download the generated file according to the query?
I already tried to do this on Postman it returns a right formatted PDF, but not in Android.

How to do it? What's the alternate? Appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am succeeded to retrieve the PDF file from the endpoint PDF table generated which is using 2 variable sent from Android as expected.

I am using these method as a request

**downloadPDF()**

```
    private void downloadPDF() {
        RestApi api = RetroFit.getInstanceRetrofit();
        Call<ResponseBody> printCall = api.getPrint(
                strDateFrom,
                strDateTo
        );
        printCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "server contacted and has file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // The most important part is in below code
                    boolean writtenToDisk = writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body());
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "file download was a success? " + writtenToDisk, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Server contact failed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

**Interface method:**

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("somepath/your_file.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> getPrint(
            @Field("keyDateFrom") String from,
            @Field("keyDateTo") String to
    );
```

And the **writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body)** to write the response into the PDF + saving it into the device

```
private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body) {
        try {
            File futureStudioIconFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                    "yourFileName.pdf");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;

            try {
                byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];

                long fileSize = body.contentLength();
                long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

                inputStream = body.byteStream();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(futureStudioIconFile);

                while (true) {
                    int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                    if (read == -1) {
                        break;
                    }

                    outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                    fileSizeDownloaded += read;

                    Log.d("TAG", "file download: " + fileSizeDownloaded + " of " + fileSize);
                }

                outputStream.flush();

                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }

                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Hopes my confusion helps someone outhere :P